# Why the arguments to the format specifiers are not getting printed properly?

Tags: c, syntax, printf, format-specifiers

I'm learning C and for some reason my `%s` doesn't print out nothing like it should. It's just random characters and with `%d` it always prints a number that's like 4600688 and not like the 12 I set it to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("why is %s happening to me"), "this";
    return 0;
}
```

This results in:

> Why is PE happening to me

(and the `return` text).

Is this a compiler error or how can I fix this?

Comment: ..What is "PE"?

Answer (score 7):

In your code

```
 printf("why is %s happening to me"), "this";
```

should be

```
 printf("why is %s happening to me", "this");
```

Otherwise, you are invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by missing to supply the required argument for `%s` conversion specifier, as required by the `printf()` function signature.

Quoting the `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.3

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);
> ```
>
> The `printf` function is equivalent to `fprintf` with the argument `stdout` interposed
>   before the arguments to `printf`.

and, from §7.21.6.1, "The `fprintf` function" (*emphasis mine*)

> The `fprintf` function writes output to the stream pointed to by `stream`, **under control
>   of the string pointed to by `format` that specifies how subsequent arguments are
>   converted for output. If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is
>   undefined.**

---

That said, this compiles fine, as the ***syntax*** is valid, thanks to  (*or blame*) the [comma-operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).